# What is the maximum number of rows in a clustered index on datetime column?

Tags: sql-server-2008, index

I would like know what the max no of rows is in a clustered index (non-unique) on a `datetime` column table in SQL Server 2008R2.

Comment: I'm curious myself. I'd like to think there wasn't one.

Answer (score 7):

The number of rows is limited only by available storage. i.e. there isn't one.

[Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

I suspect it might actually be 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 rows (maximum size of a bigint). To put that number of rows into context, if you inserted a billion rows per day, it would take approximately 25,269,512 years to exhaust.

Update: please read comments below, as they talk specifically about the uniqueifier.

Comment: Thanks, am in under impression that only 2 billion records because it internally creates integer(4 byte key size) range is -ve 2,147,483,648 To +ve 2,147,483,647  . since index key use positive number

Comment: Is clustered index(non-unique) on datetime column key size is Bigint?

Comment: Accounting for the uniquifier it is actually 2^32*2^64 records  which far exceeds the amount of data which you can store in the maximum allowed database size of 524,272 terabytes. I don't feel like going through the exact calculations but I think when you [account for all overhead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178085.aspx) you could store in the range of 15 to 25 quadrillion rows in a database in this scenario IF the only thing being stored was the datetime value.

Comment: Good point.   .........

Comment: Basically, it's more rows than you can shake a stick at!

Comment: @GlennStevens - The uniqueifier only appears on rows that are actually duplicates. Though I suppose given `datetime`s precison of 300 ticks per second and the range '17530101' to '99991231' there are "only" 78,075,005,760,000 unique possibilities so most would be dupes.

Comment: @Martin - According to this link(details) with uniquifier if duplicates  exceeds 2,147,483,647 then it will fail http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2082/understanding-and-examining-the-uniquifier-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Martin - we do import 3 million/day and data granularity is hourly so with uniquifier on datetime column,how many duplicates per day would be? and what is the max duplicates could have in a table. Thanks

Comment: sounds like you could work that out youself, no? also, "data granularity is hourly " - do you mean the smallest 'tick' is the hour? That would be unusual to say the least!

Comment: Just would like to confirm, Yes, smallest tick is hour and  if we exceeds 2,147,483,647 duplicate values then it would fail..

Comment: Is there any way(TSQL) to find out max(uniquifier key value) in a uniquifier index table --Thanks